# Cant Figure Out How To display Only the post details for the post I have clicked on

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

So I have this code here and I would like to display post details from firebase for the post which I have clicked on, but instead, it lists post details for every single post in the database one after another.

Can anyone help me figure out how I can make it so that when A post is clicked, details will show for only the post which was clicked, and not for all of the posts? Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

The Info I would like to display on the post is
postTitle
postDesc
postAuthor

Here is what the firebase looks like
[image: Firebase Image]

Code Here:

```
import 'package:tennis_event_app/services/crud.dart';
import 'package:tennis_event_app/views/create_blog.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  CrudMethods crudMethods = new CrudMethods();

  QuerySnapshot? blogSnapshot;

  @override
  void initState() {
    crudMethods.getData()?.then((result) {
      blogSnapshot = result;
      setState(() {});
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  Widget blogsList() {
    return Container(
      child: ListView.builder(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 24),
        itemCount: blogSnapshot!.docs.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return BlogTile(
            author: blogSnapshot!.docs[index].get('author'),
            title: blogSnapshot!.docs[index].get('title'),
            desc: blogSnapshot!.docs[index].get('desc'),
            imgUrl: blogSnapshot!.docs[index].get('imgUrl'),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              "Flutter",
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22),
            ),
            Text(
              "Blog",
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22, color: Colors.blue),
            )
          ],
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        elevation: 0.0,
      ),
      body: Container(
          child: blogSnapshot != null
              ? blogsList()
              : Container(
                  child: Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                ))),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.push(
              context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => CreateBlog()));
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class BlogTile extends StatelessWidget {
  final String imgUrl, title, desc, author;
  BlogTile(
      {required this.author,
      required this.desc,
      required this.imgUrl,
      required this.title});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 16, right: 16, left: 16),
      child: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            child: ClipRRect(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8)),
              child: Image.network(
                imgUrl,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                height: 170,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            height: 170,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.black45.withOpacity(0.3),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6)),
          ),
          Container(
              height: 170,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(
                    title,
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 4),
                  Text(
                    '$desc',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 17, fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 4,
                  ),
                  Text(author),
                ],
              )),
          Container(
            child: SizedBox(
              height: 170,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              child: TextButton(
                style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                  textStyle: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.push(context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => DetailPage()));
                },
                child: const Text(''),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class DetailPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DetailPageState createState() => _DetailPageState();
}

class _DetailPageState extends State<DetailPage> {
  CrudMethods crudMethods = new CrudMethods();

  QuerySnapshot? blogSnapshot;

  @override
  void initState() {
    crudMethods.getData()?.then((result) {
      blogSnapshot = result;
      setState(() {});
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  Widget blogsList2() {
    return Container(
      child: ListView.builder(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 24),
        itemCount: blogSnapshot!.docs.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return PageContent(
            postAuthor: blogSnapshot!.docs[index].get('postAuthor'),
            postTitle: blogSnapshot!.docs[index].get('postTitle'),
            postDesc: blogSnapshot!.docs[index].get('postDesc'),
            imgUrl: blogSnapshot!.docs[index].get('imgUrl'),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              "Flutter",
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22),
            ),
            Text(
              "Blog",
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22, color: Colors.blue),
            )
          ],
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        elevation: 0.0,
      ),
      body: Container(
          child: blogSnapshot != null
              ? blogsList2()
              : Container(
                  child: Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                ))),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.push(
              context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => CreateBlog()));
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class PageContent extends StatelessWidget {
  final String imgUrl, postTitle, postDesc, postAuthor;
  PageContent(
      {required this.postAuthor,
      required this.postDesc,
      required this.imgUrl,
      required this.postTitle});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 16, right: 16, left: 16),
        child: Card(
          child: ListTile(
          title: Text(
            postTitle,
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
          ),
          subtitle: Text(
            '$postDesc',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 17, fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
          ),

        )
        )
        );
  }
}
```

I also reference crud.dart in that code, so incase you need it, here it is:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'dart:collection';

class CrudMethods {
  Future<void> addData(blogData) async {
    print(blogData);
    FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("blogs")
        .add(blogData)
        .then((value) => print(value))
        .catchError((e) {
      print(e);
    });
  }
  

  getData() async {
    return await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("blogs")
        .orderBy("ts", descending: true)
        .get();
  }
}
```

Thank you again for any help!

Answer (score 1):

First I would recommend to modelize your data in an object for exemple a class `Article` that is easier to serialize and manipulate.

Then instead of requesting another time the database you should save your data in a `List<Article>` for example then you only update this list on refresh from your main page. That way you don'y manipulate a QuerySnapshot or Future but just your list of objects.

Finally and to answer your question, you could simply pass the clicked item `Article` to your details page and only display its content. Because here, you have the same construction as your main page with the same request that is resent.

Usually you can build your route like that (adding a parameter to your details with the index you clicked on for example)

```
onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.push(context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => DetailPage(article: _data[i])));
                },
```

Here is an article on serialization from [Flutter docs](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json), it shows how to build your model with the toMap, toJson and fromJson methods.

Comment: What would I need to change in order to modelize my data in an object? I’m not really sure what to do here, I’m new to flutter

Comment: Read and implement the following from flutterfire https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/#typing-collectionreference-and-documentreference